# When creating a custom file extension, is it possible to assign it an icon different from the application icon?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello wonderful people!

I have created some code for an application which upon startup, simply makes sure the registry has a key for my own file extension (or I guess 'class', as Windows calls it). It allows me to double-click a file with said extension and have it open with my program. Simple.

My query is this; is it possible for me to change the icon for this file class, to be different from the icon of my application? I would prefer to have some different icons for the various file extensions I'm registering, much in the same way that Photoshop for example gives a different icon for .PSD files than the actual application icon.

In simpler terms, I would like to mimic this behaviour but with my own icons and application:

Photoshop (the actual application):

[image: photoshop exe icon]

Photoshop Document file:

[image: .psd file icon]

I am working in C# and WPF. And I should also specify that the solution I'm looking for should be able to work in a scenario where I was to send my application to someone else to install on their computer; they should be able to see all the icons as described. I'd kindly request that in your answers you provide code examples, as I am not particularly familiar with working directly with the registry.

I should also specify that my application does have an icon, and this is currently what the custom filetype displays in Windows Explorer.

Comment: This is something the installer does for you, that is register file types.  Which installer are you using?  InstallShield?  Wix?  Everything you need to do this is built into these installers.  There is no need to write any code.

Comment: I am not using an installer, the app isn't developed yet. Regardless, that doesn't answer the question.